# How to change DependentRangeAxis in Areachart

Tags: xaml, charts, winrt-xaml, stacked-area-chart, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm using WinRT-toolkit AreaChart, I need to change DependentRangeAxis directly in XAML code, I want to set a fixed range from 1 to 5.

```
<Series:Chart
            x:Name="QuestionHistory"
            Title="Area Chart">
        <Series:AreaSeries 
            Title="MediaRisposte"
            AnimationSequence="LastToFirst"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
            DependentRangeAxis="???"
            IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    </Series:Chart>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ((BarSeries)this.LikesChart.Series[0]).IndependentAxis = new LinearAxis() { Minimum = 0, Maximum = 5, Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y };
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's nearly 9 years late but I have to use that WinRT chart for a project so I figured I'd answer it in hopes that it has value to someone. The only options you'll be able to choose are `DateTimeAxis` and `LinearAxis`. Here's how you change it in XAML...

```html
<Series:Chart
  x:Name="QuestionHistory"
  Title="Area Chart">
  <Series:AreaSeries
    Title="MediaRisposte"
    AnimationSequence="LastToFirst"
    IndependentValueBinding="{Bindng Name}"
    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
    IsSelectionEnabled="True">
    <Series:AreaSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
      <Series:LinearAxis/>
    </Series:AreaSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
  </Series:AreaSeries>
</Series:Chart>
```